# Generating easy report takes too long (~10-12s) - phpJasper laravel

Tags: laravel, jasper-reports

I am using this package https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper-laravel for generating jasper reports. I have created simple report in JasperStudio (Only one H1 text header and two parameters). Via Laravel 10 rest api I am starting $jasper->process... with above mentioned two text parameters, which I am passing through the API. Route is only behind the basic laravel api middleware. When I run the route for generating report via postman, response time is about 10-12s. When I run the same command (which I got with the output method) in terminal, report is done by 4-5s. In both cases, I have noticed, that java app is opened with some delay. ~3-4s in first scenario, ~2s in second scenario. Also I have tried to use just plain exec() with command from output, but the result is the same. Also, I have run command without API, directly from controller. No difference.

Anyway, this is also not good performance for such a easy report. Therefore, I would like to ask, why the response time is so long? Has anybody this kind of performance issues with jaspe reports? Thank you in advanced for the help.

I am using Mac OSX 14 (Sonoma), PHP 8 an Laravel 10, java v1.8.

Here is a command:

```
'/Users/svoby/www/localhost/test/vendor/geekcom/phpjasper-laravel/src/../bin/jasperstarter/bin/jasperstarter -v process "/Users/svoby/www/localhost/test/resources/reports/contacts/contact_detail.jrxml" -o "/Users/svoby/www/localhost/test/storage/reports/contact_detail" -f pdf -P  firstname="John"   surname="Doe"';
```

### Update

I did not figure out, above mentioned issue. Anyway, I ended up with Jasper Server community edition (https://community.jaspersoft.com/files/file/18-jasperreports-server-community-edition/). I have downloaded and installed so far locally (on mac). Advantage of this approach is, that they have REST API to the reports, which are in Jasper Server. Also, they have PHP client [https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-php-client] (just wrapper of native JS REST API). I have tested it in Laravel 10, and works seamlessly. Response times are ~0.5-1.0s for easy report. I hope, that this new information will help someone.